# Como abrir link contido no Javadoc pelo Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Tem como eu abrir um arquivo no Eclipse a partir de um link contido em um trecho de Javadoc? No caso esse arquivo seria um XML.

Comment: Não percebi a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar um link para uma URL qualquer com a tag `{@link URL}`. Veja a [documentação](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).

Então basta colocar o arquivo num servidor qualquer e colocar a URL. Provavelmente não dá pra fazer relativo à classe ou ao projeto.